# Sql statement for mutually exclusive events

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to run an sql statement on an iSeries that will output retuls based on a type parameter I pass in.

Just say mytable has a field called field1.  field1 contains Y,N and NULL values.

A type of 'Y' should return just 'Y' values.
A type of 'N' should return not 'Y' values. (ie. Null, N and any other junk in the field)

I tried this...

```
        select *
          from mytable
          where field1 in case when :type = 'Y' then 'Y'
               else (select field1 from mytable where field1 <> 'Y') end
```

However, this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the logic you are looking for is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE (:type = 'Y' AND field1 IS NOT null AND field1 = 'Y')
   OR (:type <> 'Y' AND (field1 IS null OR field1 <> 'Y'))
```

(keep in mind the fact that short-circuit logic is **not** garuanteed with SQL...)

Remember that `null` doesn't really compare to anything, and it's best to call out the fact that you actually *want* it (in the second case).